# use match, limit, sort, and lookup together in mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 colletcions:

1. User
2. Notification

User:

```
{
  id:1,
  name:ABC
},
{
  id:2,
  name:ABC2
},
{
  id:3,
  name:ABC3
}
```

Notification:

```
{
  id:1,
  userId:1,
  read:false,
  info: 'Notification for user 1'
},{
  id:2,
  userId:2,
  read:false,
  info: 'Notification for user 2'
},{
  id:3,
  userId:3,
  read:false,
  info: 'Notification for user 3'
}
```

I want to fetch Notifications data with match (read:false), sort(descending order on createdAt), limit(5) and lookup on user collection based on user id in notification data

Query should return:

```
[{
  id:1,
  userId:1,
  read:false,
  info: 'Notification for user 1'
  username:ABC
},{
  id:2,
  userId:2,
  read:false,
  info: 'Notification for user 2'
  username:ABC2
},{
  id:3,
  userId:3,
  read:false,
  info: 'Notification for user 3'
  username:ABC3
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

- `$match` to match your conditions
- `$lookup` to join user collection
- `$unwind` deconstruct user array because its an array and we need object
- `$project` to show required fields
- `$sort` by `createdAt` descending order
- `$limit` 5 documents

```
db.notification.aggregate([
  { $match: { read: false } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "user",
      as: "user",
      localField: "userId",
      foreignField: "id"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$user" },
  {
    $project: {
      id: 1,
      userId: 1,
      read: 1,
      info: 1,
      username: "$user.name"
    }
  },
  { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
  { $limit: 5 }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zik-KgoIMqx)

Comment: Thanks @turivishal for your time. this returns "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" in node

Comment: you need to provide details how you are using and executing query.

Comment: Notification.aggregate([
        { $match: { read: false } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            as: "user",
            localField: "clientId",
            foreignField: "id"
          }
        },
        { $unwind: "$user" },
        {
          $project: {
            id: 1,
            clientId: 1,
            read: 1,
            username: "$user"
          }
        },
        { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
        { $limit: 5 }
      ]).then(....)

Comment: i hope this makes the problem a bit clear @turivishal

Comment: no please show how you are printing records, where it returns error, i think you have to look at the documentation in mongoose https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate